# how to create viber like application?

Tags: iphone, voip

is there any tutorial on making viber like application for ipad and iphone?
is there any api or tutorial apps to learn about the voip or wifi configuration to texting and calling from iphone or ipad also from 3G for ipad2
thanks in advance

Comment: what is this viber? add some screenshot or some details..!!

Comment: @Sarah very popular voip skype type app for use on mobile phones.  Difference is it uses your phone numbers as your id so no signup.

Comment: @TobyAllen : thats true..even i know that but thing is just by giving the name of any app, you can not predict that anybody would be familiar with the same. hence commented so.. :)

Comment: @Sarah, except I think you might have proved that almost everyone is familiar with Viber and those that aren't wouldn't be able to answer the question anyway?  I'm sorry I missed the sarcasm in your comment.

Comment: @TobyAllen how that came into picture? i guess i was not telling him rudely,was just suggesting him. why r u taking it in wrong way,also it was just a suggestion as he is a newbie nothing else.

Comment: oh sorry for this kind of question. And yes @sarah it is an application through which we can call to other peoples who use it on iphone using wifi connection and it's free as it is uses wifi to connect also can send sms in wifi connection is it awesome right

Comment: Hello Aalok See my component in binpress.com, and  Its name is Lazy Scroll Image Load, download it and see it.. you have to login with github in it to download it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no step-by-step tutorial for this kind of application. I advise you to complete these four steps:

1. Read iPhone/iPad application guidelines from http://developer.apple.com/
2. Find some VOIP open source projects and inspect them.
3. Read the VOIP standards.
4. Try to transfer VOIP parts from open source projects to your iOS project.

That should be enough to write a VOIP client.